# IE CSS is not implementing box-shadow when deployed to server

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer-9

I am using some css to add a corner radius and box shadow to a div in my asp.net project

```
.DesktopContainerDiv
{
    background-color:#C4D5E9;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    padding:10px;
    width:60%;
    min-width:800px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align:center;
    min-height:200px
}
```

This works fine when I run through the Visual Studio IDE (Hitting F5). But when I deploy it to my web server, if I load a page using IE9 is doesn't display the box shadow and radius (Firefox and Chrome both show it correctly).

I have tried using UltiDev and IIS web servers and both behave the same so that eliminates that.

IE must be picking up the sytlesheet because it is turning the background blue so I can't understand what the difference is between running in IDE and web server is.

Comment: have you tried to use -ms-box-shadow?

Comment: When the project is loaded, open the developers tab (F12 in IE). Is the **Browser Mode** the same in both the IDE version and production version? (e.g. Both say IE9, or IE9 Compatibility View)

Comment: @sam - thanks for the pointer - the issue was that IE9 was in compatability mode

Comment: @MattWilko glad to help. I wonder if Elliot's solution will force all visitors into IE9 rather than IE9 Compatibility mode. I'd be interested to hear. Anyway, good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me once before and the problem was solved by making sure the compatability mode was set to IE9

You can force this by putting

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

into your `<head>`

*Edit*: Or try:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't seem to have any effect. I load the page and it if I press F12 it always shows IE9 compatibility view is ticked. I can change to IE9 (which then displays correctly) but if I close the browser and reopen it goes back to compatibility view.

Comment: Ah - I think this setting is actually working but because my web server is an 'intranet site' the IE setting was being overridden but for some reason it doesn't think that the VS IDE is intranet (adding to the confusion) Thanks